# CoreData. Когда его нужно использовать, и когда не нужно

Tags: ios, coredata

> CoreData. Когда его нужно использовать, и когда не нужно?

Такой вопрос попался на собеседовании, не могу найти информации по этому вопросу, есть небольшие разборы минусов этого способа, но отсутствие опыта разработки на iOS мешает понять, что и когда предпочтительней, хотелось бы услышать от опытных разработчиков, когда стоит использовать `core data`, а когда нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data стоит использовать только в том случае, когда нужно хранить большие объемы данных и потом отображать их оффлайн.

Например, вам требуется в получить список ферм в какой-нибудь деревне, которые вам нужно проверить, а потом съездить на каждую ферму и создать отчет о каждой ферме и выгрузить их на сервер. Логично, что чтобы получить и потом отгрузить отчеты вам требуется интернет. Следовательно, вы подключаетесь к интернету, получаете список ферм, отключаетесь от интернета, едете в деревню, создаете отчеты, сохраняете их и потом, найдя хороший интернет выгружаете их на сервер. На этапе загрузке списка ферм вы загружаете их в Core Data (далее "база данных") затем отключаетесь от интернета, открываете приложение, подгружается список из базы данных и вы его видите, далее вы создаете отчеты, которые также сохраняются в базу данных. После подключения к интернету вы выгружаете отчеты, которые вы сохранили ранее в базу данных, когда у вас не было интернета.

Comment: Немного дополню, основная задача Core Data сохранять большой объем информации, и дает возможность использовать данную информацию после перезапуска приложения, без необходимости повторного запроса данных с сервера. (например как сказано выше, когда у вас нет соединения с интернетом)

Comment: @VitaliEller я думаю что это было понятно, так как ехать в деревню и держать приложение на экране телефона было бы абсурдно) но все равно спасибо

Comment: не думаю, что с таким ответом вы прошли бы интервью.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko критикуешь? Предлагай!

Comment: @GermanPolyansky я так понимаю, вы тут новенький - тут принято обращаться на вы. А касательно вашей просьбы - см ниже

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko есть такое выражение "Критикуешь - предлагай", прошу извинений если оскорбил Вас или затронул Ваше достоинство.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу свой вариант ответа.

Во первых из вопроса не совсем понятно, что имеется ввиду под "не использовать": не использовать никаких инструментов ORM / хранения данных и доступа к ним, или не использовать конкретно core data, а использовать, например, SQLite. Попробую ответить на оба вопроса.

1) Использовать core data или не использовать каких persistent store/object graph/ORM вообще.

В вашем приложении, не зависимо от того, что оно делает (если оно хоть чуть чуть сложнее Hello World) есть model layer, который состоит из объектов и отношений между ними (object-relational mapping). Все это дело надо как то хранить, использовать, обновлять, кэшировать и так далее. Вот тут мы приходим к core data. Не зависимо от того, как работает ваша модель, core data может вам сэкономить кучу времени (по утверждению apple, ваш код для операций с моделью уменьшится на 50-70%) и кучу головной боли.

Короче говоря, например, у вас есть база данных, и есть объекты модели - классы, которые вы строите на основании данных из БД, другими словами преобразуете данные из базы данных в ORM(object-relational mapping). Вот это одна из основных функций core data.

Что умеет делать core data:

> - Отслеживать изменения модели и предоставлять undo/redo
> - Заниматься распространением изменений, включая поддержание отношений между объектами
> - Делать lazy loading, включая частичную загрузку объектов.
> - Автоматическая валидация значений, включая проверку, того, что значения находятся в допустимых пределах
> - Инструменты для миграции схем (миграции баз данных)
> - Опциональная интеграция с controller layer для поддержки синхронизации с юзер интерфейсом
> - Группировка, фильтрация и организация данных в памяти
> - Автоматическая поддержка сохранения данных во внешних репозиториях.

Не представляю приложение, которое не делает хоть что-то из выше описанного (а скорее всего почти все).

Наиболее традиционный пример использования core data - синхронизация данных клиент-сервер, где часть базы данных с сервера удобнее хранить на клиенте (например, для экономии трафика, чтобы не грузить одни и те же данные снова и снова, или для доступа к ним в оффлайн). Но это далеко не все, что можно делать при помощи core data - например, если вы пишете игру в которой есть объекты и отношения между ними (например, Diablo, где у вас есть меч, в нем есть слот в котором есть камень и так далее; надеюсь никто не думает, что хранить это все в массиве в синглтоне - хорошая идея)  - core data вам сильно упростит жизнь.

У многих людей есть заблуждение, что core data это обертка для SQLite. Это в корне неверно. Во первых core data не обязательно использует SQLite для хранения данных - кроме него может использоваться XML и binary, либо core data может хранить все объекты в памяти без on-disk storage. Во вторых core data имплементирует множество методов, которые полностью отвечают за lifecycle объектов, менеджмент отношений между ними и многое другое. Например, в core data можно указать, что делать с зависимыми объектами, когда объект удаляется (в частности, можно удалить зависимые объекты, можно убрать зависимость, можно запретить удаление объекта пока есть хоть одна зависимость).

Из этого можно сделать вывод, что core data помогает с менеджментом object graphs (отношения/зависимости между объектами), и помогает организовать persistent storage (сохранение данных между сессиями).

Ну и ответ на вопрос: я бы сказал, использование core data сэкономит вам время при написании любого приложения, в котором есть более-менее сложный object graph, а если еще надо и persistent store, то даже и думать нечего.

Более конкретные примеры:

- кэширование данных с сервера локально
- быстрый доступ к данным из хранилища
- сложные отношения между объектами
- undo/redo
- частичная загрузка объектов из локального хранилища в память
- вывод данных из модели в вью используя UITableView (при помощи NSFetchedResultsController)

Где не стоит использовать core data: в любом приложении, где это будет "overkill". Если вся ваша модель, это два массива и 3 булеана, то core data вам ничего не сэкономит, а только добавит время разработки.

2) где использовать core data, а где что-то другое.

Для примера, рассмотрим вариант использования core data или SQLite.

Как я уже писал, многие полагают, что core data это обертка для SQLite. Вот примерный список различий:

база данных (в нашем случае SQLite)

- основная функция - хранение и доступ к данным
- работает с данными сохраненными на диск
- хранит данные никак не управляя их поведением (core data помогает управлять объектами, как в примере выше с удалением зависимых обектов)
- может быть транзакционной, thread-safe
- может редактировать таблицы без загрузки в память
- периодически сохраняется на диск
- работает медленно при создании миллионов новых записей

Core Data:

- основная функция управление отношениями объектов (хотя запись/чтение тоже важные функции поддерживаемые core data)
- работает только с объектами в памяти (хотя они могут lazy загружаться с диска)
- работает с полноценными объектами, которые сами управляют своим поведением и могут наследоваться для большей кастомизации
- не транзакционная, работает на одном потоке (из моего опыта это самое ужасное в core data)
- работает только с объектами в памяти

Таким образом, исходя из ваших задач, можно сказать, что если основная цель, это иметь базу данных и механизмы доступа к ней, то SQLite отличное решение (найти к нему на github набор функций чтения и записи). Если же вы отталкиваетесь от ORM, и вам нужна система, которая сможет этим всем умно управлять и уберет эту всю нагрузку с вас, как разработчика, тогда наверно core data.

В завершение: недавно имел возможность поколдовать с [realm](https://realm.io/). Очень хороший инструмент - пытается как то избавиться от всех проблем SQLite и Core Data. При этом open source. Я бы сказал, при выборе между ним и core data, я бы выбрал realm.

Comment: спасибо огромное, очень доступно объяснили)

Comment: Realm штука хорошая, но есть нюанс: "String sorting and case insensitive queries are only supported for character sets in ‘Latin Basic’, ‘Latin Supplement’, ‘Latin Extended A’, ‘Latin Extended B’ (UTF-8 range 0-591)." И он не один, но этот - самый существенный.

Comment: @crazyhorse именно по этому realm оупен сорс :)

Comment: Как правило, это решающий фактор при выборе фреймворка для проекта. Отсутствие локализации, это не 2.0, как они себя позиционируют, а 0.2. И насчет оупенсорса - до релиза был не совсем уж и оупэн, бинарники были. Сейчас - не в теме, а ресёрчить некогда.

Comment: @crazyhorse помните, что вы всегда можете дать им денег, чтоб вам написали фичу какую надо